# Where to save a file to be accessable via FileInputStream

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream

I need a `FileInputStream` from a file but I don't know where to place the file.

I wrote this code:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/Key.p12");
```

But, where should I save file `Key.p12`?

Comment: in directory src/test/resources.

Comment: Yes, but in app/src/test, there doesnt exist a dir called "resources". Only "res". Maybe it works when i create a dir called "resources"...

Answer (score 2):

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/Key.p12");
```

There is no `src/test/resources/` directory on any Android device.

> Yes, but in app/src/test, there doesnt exist a dir called "resources". Only "res". Maybe it works when i create a dir called "resources"...

No, it will not. `FileInputStream` will only work for things that are files *on the device*. Anything packaged in your APK will *not* be files on the device.

Instead, store this file in `app/src/main/assets/`. Then, use `AssetManager` and `open()` to get an `InputStream` on that asset.

Comment: Sounds good, but i main does not have an assets-dir, just a java and a res dir.

Answer (score 0):

where ever you want to put the file 
just copy the destination and paste it in the constructor